# Enabling (python) plugins on QGIS3 (Linux)?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I'm running qgis 3.0.3 in Fedora 28 and I seem to have several, related problems with plugins.

Plugins --> Manage and Install Plugins: the window that opens shows 7 pre-installed plugins (I think there used to be 8 before, how come?).

Under the Settings tab, it says that "no python support detected, thus no settings available"

What dependency am I missing on my system?

Also, the search from the search field doesn't seem to work, it searches only through the 7 available plugins.

I downloaded a plugin from qgis and extracted it to

`/home/myyser/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins` but it's not being loaded.

Any hints?

Comment: did you install qgis-python?

Comment: Nope, not until now. This should be marked as a soft dependency by the package maintainer. Many thanks for your help! It now works as it should.

Comment: @Flo, please accept the answer if it works, so others can see that your issue was solved.

Comment: Where can one find qgis-python?

Answer (score 4):

Try to find name of package `python3-qgis` in Fedora package manager (worked for me in Fedora 30).

Comment: In fedora 33 this worked:     'dnf install python3-qgis'

Answer (score 2):

There is an optional `qgis-python` package that needs to be installed for the python plugins to work.

Comment: I am having a hard time finding this package.  Do you happen to know where to get it?

Comment: Agreed, where can one find qgis-python?