# Search yields no results in plugins menu

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3, installation

I can't manage to figure out why I can't download any plugins. I have an Internet connection, but it seems like QGIS can't access the online repository of plugins.

As an example, I'd like to download the OpenStreetMaps plugin. When I type anything into the search bar (even a single letter), no hits come back. Any ideas about what to do here?

Also, the version I am using is 3.10.10 - A Coruña. Using 64 bit on Mac OS.

[image: Search bar of plugin menu]

UPDATE:

Issue has been solved by updating my mac OS as QGIS only supports OS above 10.13 (High Sierra I believe?)

Comment: I just asked a related question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/341486/unable-to-install-plugins-in-qgis-3-10-for-mac-no-python-support-detected. While you don’t seem to have any plugins, I at least have a handful of them. But none that are created with Python. So for me I believe it’s a Python issue. Not sure if that’s of any help for you...

Comment: I just solved my problem by upgrading my Mac OS from Sierra 10.12 to Mojave 10.14. The latest QGIS download requires a minimum of High Sierra 10.13 https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html. What Mac OS are you using? Could this be your problem?

Comment: @KristenG. I also just discovered that this was the issue and will be updating my question accordingly!