# MMQGIS plugin in QGIS 3.10 Mac version?

Tags: qgis, geocoding, mmqgis

I'm new to QGIS.  I'm interested in geocoding addressed and have seen from research that the MMQGIS plugin is a great resource.  I do not see this as a preloaded plugin (most references online indicate that it generally is).

I downloaded a MMQGIS folder of the current plugin and tried to drop that under contents in the QGIS content folder but that was unsuccessful.  Any assistance or information (even just knowing why it isn't a preloaded plug in) would be great.

Answer (score 4):

You can install the MMQGIS plugin from *Plugins ~> Manage and Install Plugins* menu.

Search for `mmqgis` plugin, select it and click on <kbd>Install plugin</kbd>.

If you can't find it, check that you have the repository well configured in the *Plugins | Settings* tab.

If you see a `No Python support detected` message there, that is another problem and the following question/answer may help you:

- [Unable to install plugins in QGIS 3.10 for Mac. No python support detected](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/341486/unable-to-install-plugins-in-qgis-3-10-for-mac-no-python-support-detected)