# Why is my PYTHONPATH setting itself to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, macos

I'm trying to cleanup Python on my Mac. I keep getting this message in Terminal:

> Your PYTHONPATH points to a site-packages dir for Python 3.x but you
>   are running Python 2.x!
>        PYTHONPATH is currently: "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Resources/python"
>        You should `unset PYTHONPATH` to fix this.

What is going on? Why does QGIS keep setting my PYTHONPATH to itself? I keep resetting my PYTHONPATH with `unset PYTHONPATH` but then this keeps happening anyway.

**Update 1:** I think Python 2 and Python 3 both use the same PYTHONPATH, so I will have to figure out a workaround. The answers on this SE post may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34066261/how-to-set-different-pythonpath-variables-for-python3-and-python2-respectively. Will post an update if I get it working...

**Update 2 (and Solution):** The problem is that I set my .bash_profile to QGIS. I forgot I had done this trying to solve [another problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/341486/unable-to-install-plugins-in-qgis-3-10-for-mac-no-python-support-detected) I had several months ago, which didn't work, but I never reversed the changes I made. So, problem officially solved.

Comment: If it was added to your `.bash_profile` when it was installed, it will keep on coming back every time you start a new shell until you take it out from there. (Maybe also inspect `.bashrc` and `.profile` if they exist in your home directory, and strictly speaking also any files sourced by any of these.)

Comment: @tripleee before I consider removing it do you know why QGIS would have added itself to it? Or why any application would add itself to the `.bash_profile`?

Comment: @triplee Wait a second. Maybe this makes sense. Maybe I don't want to remove it. Maybe it's not a problem when I'm using Python 3. Is this just an issue of my having both Python 2 and 3 on my computer at the same time? Is there only one PYTHONPATH between them that they share? Is that what's causing the issue?

Comment: Yup, this SE thread is asking the question more clearly than me (because I didn't realize the PYTHONPATH was the same for both installs). I'll try these answers out... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34066261/how-to-set-different-pythonpath-variables-for-python3-and-python2-respectively

Comment: @tripleee Commenting here as well as on my SO post. It was me who changed it. D'oh. I just had zero memory of doing it until I re-read this question I had posted a few months ago. I removed those lines and now everything is working. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/341486/unable-to-install-plugins-in-qgis-3-10-for-mac-no-python-support-detected